# Add grid column dynamically in xaml

Tags: wpf, triggers, grid

Is there any way I can add grid column dynamically in xaml (e.g. using trigger/datatrigger)?
The case is that I want to add/remove grid column depending on the Visibility property that is binded to that grid.

Comment: Rather than add/remove the column you can just make the column visible/invisible.

Comment: Well, actually there is no "Visibility" property for grid column

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an exact solution to your problem, but you could try something like this.

```xml
<Grid Name="theGrid">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Name="columnToHide" />
       <ColumnDefinition />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <StackPanel Name="stackToHide" Grid.Column="0">
        <Button>hello</Button>
   </StackPanel>
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">Bye</Button>
</Grid>
```

```csharp
bool visible = true;
GridLength width;
GridLength height;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (visible)
    {
        GridLength zero = new GridLength(0);
        width = columnToHide.Width;    //save original height and width
        columnToHide.Width = zero; //make column invisible
        visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        columnToHide.Width = width; //restore original width
        visible = true;
    }
}
```

You could also try putting column content inside a container and changing the Visibility property on that, although that wouldn't cause any resizing of grid content, and you'd be left with space where the column used to be.

Comment: actually, I can't use this solution. The solution should be included in xaml or ViewModel as I'm not using code behind

Comment: Ah. In that case I'm not sure I can help, sorry. Any reason you don't want to indulge in a code behind, out of curiosity?